# form value disappear when clicked

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a question with 6 radio buttons, so they are coded 1,2,3,4,5,99, there is also a text box to enter verbatim answers. If codes 1-5 have been selected then the value in the text box will disappear, if code 99 is selected then the answer in the text box will show up.

However as soon as I click on the text box to edit the verbatim entered earlier, all texts within the text box will disappear,

ID of the text box is: Q6_99_other

And here is the script:

```
var txt = "";
$('#fieldset_Q6 input').parent().each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        //alert('checked');

        $('#Q6_99_other').on('keyup change', function () {
            txt = this.value;
        })

        var id = $(this).children().attr('id');
        if (id == 'Q6_1_99') {
            $('#Q6_99_other').val(txt);
        } else {
            $('#Q6_99_other').val('');
        }

    });
});
```

Anyone with any suggestions? perhaps I need to modify the "keyup change" part of the script?

Many thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the text box, the click event bubbles up to the parent element. This runs the click handler you've written. Since the ID of the child is not `Q6_1_99`, it executes `$('#Q6_99_other').val('')`, which clears the text field.

You can prevent this bubbling with:

```
$("#Q6_99_other").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.focus();
});
```

Also, you probably shouldn't have the `keyup change` binding inside the click handler. That means that every time the user clicks on the parent, it will bind another `keyup change` handler on the text box. You only need to do that once, not every time they click. Just do it in the top-level document.ready handler.

You also don't need to use `.each()` to bind handlers to all the elements. Event binding functions can be applied to collections, and jQuery automatically iterates over them.

Comment: Hi Barmar, you are absolutely spot on!!! As Q6_99_other is also an input under the cloud of "#fieldset_Q6 input", so it has cleared the answers. I have moved 'keyup change" function out of the each click  function, and also removed .each(), worked perfectly, many thanks!

Comment: One more question, when I have clicked on the text in the text box, the cursor will jump to the beginning of the text, any reason why? this happened to "$('#Q6_99_other').val(txt);", e.g. if txt = 'whatever', when I click on the retrieved text 'whatever', the cursor will be pointing at the beginning of the text, so it looks like '|whatever', instead of where it has been clicked on, e.g. 'wha|tever' for example.

Comment: The script now looks like the following for your reference: var txt = "";
$('#Q6_99_other').on('keyup change', function(){
txt = this.value;
})

$('#fieldset_Q6 input').parent().click(function(){
var id=$(this).children().attr('id');
if(id == 'Q6_1_99' || id == 'Q6_99_other'){$('#Q6_99_other').val(txt);}else{$('#Q6_99_other').val('');}


});

Comment: Since you're replacing `.val()` of the input box when you click, it loses track of the cursor position.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, not sure if anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You could check if the value of the field is the same as the variable, and not change it.